# selenium tests not passing with uniqueness => true

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, integration-testing, rspec2

I am using selenium and Rails3 Rspec to do a test for an app that uses some Ajax.

A form is submitted using Ajax.  Say an email and password field.

The test runs perfectly if I submit the form without validation for uniqueness.

However if I submit the form using a uniqueness validation the test fails saying the email already exists.

However this only fails if I do the test using selenium. If i fill out the form by hand and submit it, it works.

I clear out the database and run the test and the same problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Selenium tests take place in the actual browser so they write to the development database. I had to clear out my development database between tests using rake db:reset and then the tests passed.

Comment: thats weird, you should set your selenium to check in your test db, not your dev db.